# Object inside Object json error

Tags: java, json, spring, angular, httprequest

I have a http request where I passa a object inside the other object. example:

```
    DisciplinaDTO{
       private Long id_disciplina;
       private String st_nome;
       private ArrayList<AlunoListDTO> ls_alunos;
   }

   AlunoListDTO{
       private Long id_aluno;
       private String st_nome_aluno;
   }
```

And when I try to pass a Json on this object from my frontend. The terminal show me this error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.tcc.secretaria.DTO.AlunoListDTO]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.tcc.secretaria.DTO.AlunoListDTO` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 154] (through reference chain: com.tcc.secretaria.DTO.DisciplinaDTO["ls_alunos"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.tcc.secretaria.DTO.AlunoListDTO` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I think this is because I have a Object inside on other object. But how I can pass this?

My Constructor:

```
public DisciplinaDTO(Long id_disciplina, String st_nome, ArrayList<AlunoListDTO> ls_alunos) {
    this.id_disciplina = id_disciplina;
    this.st_nome = st_nome;
    this.ls_alunos = ls_alunos;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any constructor in you code ? `no Creators, like default construct, exist)` , Are you using Jackson? Jackson has a list of issues/solutions at this link >> http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception

Comment: Yes, I have. I write the code in the question @SaifMasadeh

Comment: Try to add the default constructor to both classes.

Comment: @SaifMasadeh I have the constructor for AlunoListDTO. But inside the AlunoListDTO.java. I need to create a constructor for AlunoListDTO inside of my DisciplinaDTO?

Comment: Can you share your whole code at `git hub ` ? I will try to run it locally and see what is going on